# Como converter para Banco de Dados e verificar se uma data é válida

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, formulário, data, formatação

Como converto para `YYYY-mm-dd` e verifico se uma data transmitida por um usuário via método POST é valida para minha aplicação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Método anterior removido devido à certos erros. Aqui vai uma outra forma de validar datas **brasileiras** (não testado em outros formatos).

---

Se você está no **Brasil** e ainda não conseguiu converter a data pega do seu formulário para `YYYY-mm-dd` aqui vão algumas linhas de código que podem te ajudar:

```
$data = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data))); // converte datas em formato 'br' para sql.
```

Caso esteja utilizando datas em formato 'mm/dd/YYYY' só precisa inverter 'm' e 'd' passados na função `date`.

---

Para validar datas **brasileiras** você vai precisar do seguinte:

```
$date = strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $date));
```

Muito simples, a função `strtotime` retornará `FALSE` se não conseguir converter a nossa data, que será convertida facilmente caso seja válida.

`str_replace` é usado porque ao usar barras `/` o PHP entende que estamos trabalhando com o formato `mm/dd/YYYY` em vez de `dd/mm/YYYY`. Ao usar os hífens o PHP compreende nossa data corretamente. Tal função irá converter as barras em hífens que estão presentes na `string` `$date`.

---

Se você usa datas no formato `mm/dd/YYYY` pode usar a seguinte função para validar:

```
$date = human_to_unix(unix_to_human(strtotime($date), FALSE));
    if($date==FALSE){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', 'Data inválida. Favor não inserir manualmente.');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
```

**Explicação:** o algoritmo irá pegar o valor de data `$data` passado à ele no formato `Y-m-d` e irá converte-lo em uma data em `unix`, que, se inválida retornará, provavelmente, 0. Isso ja seria suficiente para datas completamente erradas como `YY-dddd-mm`, porém para que a data seja totalmente filtrada e validada optei por mais uma camada de conversão para formato "humano" `YYYY-mm-dd` e depois para `unix`, que, ao tentar converter uma data inválida retornará 0 (FALSE). Após isso é só verificado se a data "sobreviveu" aos nossos testes e temos um retorno para uma callback_ function. :)